# Airflow 2.6: Using runtime config to determine task timeouts on manually triggered DAGs

Tags: airflow

I have a DAG that users need to occasionally trigger on the UI, with a parameter that determines which subset of data to use. Depending on the subset, the individual tasks can run for 5 minutes, or an hour. I would like to be able to pass in a task timeout (execution_timeout) from the runtime config in the UI, instead of setting the upper limit to accommodate the largest subset.

To accomplish this, I'm trying to use jinja templating inside the task definition, and setting a default value in the DAG definition.

`with DAG(
...
params={"mls_sid" : "0", "time_out" : 10}
) as dag:

```
task = PythonOperator(
    ...
    execution_timeout = timedelta(minutes="{{ params.time_out }}")
)`
```

This gives an error for using a str value inside the timedelta object. However if I wrap the jinja with int(), I am getting a base 10 value error. I believe that when loading the DAG, instead of the default value set in the DAG definition. Can I not use templating for the execution timeout, and if not, its there another way of passing in the execution_timeout at runtime, whether triggered from another DAG, the UI, or API?

Answer (score 0):

The execution_timeout parameter is a partial in the BaseOperator, and not a templated field, so jinja templating won't work.
The simplest solution I have come up with is to have a separate DAG set & reset the timeout as a Airflow Variable, and trigger the original DAG.

DAG 1:
set_time_out_variable >> trigger_pipeline >> reset_time_out_variable

DAG 2:
RandomOperator(
...
execution_timeout=timedelta(minutes=int(Variable.get('pipeline_timeout', default_var=10)))

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).